# Angular library for editing and rendering markdown

Tags: markdown, angular

Does anyone know of a good free library for editing and rendering Markdown content in an Angular 2+ SPA?

Some nice-to-haves would be:

- MD syntax highlighting in the editor
- Code support (preferably multi-language)
- FOSS
- An actively maintained project

Thank you

Comment: Maybe a library in JavaScript already helps? https://github.com/BubuAnabelas/awesome-markdown#javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can try Syncfusion Angular RichTextEditor component

- Edit WYSIWYG HTML and markdown content with a rich set of tools for modern web and mobile applications.
  = Easily incorporate into blogs editor, messages, HTML email composer, and discussion forum-like applications.
- Make a floating toolbar or inline editor that allows selection of any editable element on the page and edit in place.

https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-ui-components/angular-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the community license program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: I had no idea they offered this community license. I'm going to check this out over the weekend. Thanks!